# Pyspark unit test: how to mock sql calls (and only the sql calls)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark

I'm having trouble testing the following function

```py
# module1.py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f


spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()


def filter_big_table(
    conditions: Optional[List[str]] = None,
) -> SparkDataFrame:

    sdf = spark.sql(f"select * from SUPER_BIG_TABLE")

    if conditions:
        sdf = sdf.filter(f.col("condition_col").isin(conditions))
    return sdf
```

Here's how I've been trying to approach it with `unittest.mock` and `pytest`:

```py
#conftest.py
import pytest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark():
    return SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("unit_tests").getOrCreate()
```

And the actual test, where I create a fake DataFrame with tuple fixtures so that I don't have to actually run this query `spark.sql(f"select * from SUPER_BIG_TABLE")`.

```py
# test.py
from unittest.mock import patch

from module1 import filter_big_table
from . import assert_sdf_equal  # Helper function


DATA_FIXTURE = List[Tuple[str, int]]
DATA_SCHEMA = StructType

@patch("pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql")
def test_filter_big_table(mock_data, spark):
    
    input_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(DATA_FIXTURE, DATA_SCHEMA)
    mock_data.return_value = input_sdf

    expected_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(DATA_FIXTURE, DATA_SCHEMA)
    output_sdf = filter_big_table()

    # Passing no conditions should return the same spark dataframe
    assert_sdf_equal(output_sdf, expected_sdf)
```

The error I keep getting, however, is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sql'`.

I feel this is because of the way the module is getting the current spark session on the `module1.py`, but I didn't want the module to change for the test to pass. I've been toying around with different kinds of mocks, to no avail.

**Edit**

Tried using `@patch("module1.spark")` instead, but instead of an AttributeError, I receive a mock object instead of the `input_sdf` fixture. Also tried replacing `mock_data.return_value` for `mock_data.side_effects`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the module in order for it to work :(

Now the session is created inside the function.

```py
# module1.py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f


def filter_big_table(
    conditions: Optional[List[str]] = None,
) -> SparkDataFrame:
    spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
    sdf = spark.sql(f"select * from SUPER_BIG_TABLE")

    if conditions:
        sdf = sdf.filter(f.col("condition_col").isin(conditions))
    return sdf
```

And the decorator is `@patch("module1.SparkSession.sql")`

That way no name collisions occur and the mock successfully replaces the `sql` method.

Answer (score 0):

I still had to modify your module1 a little bit, but this could still be instructive.

The line:

```
spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
```

Does not necessarily create a spark object with a sql property, resulting in:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
None does not have the attribute 'sql'
```

If you initialise spark differently:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('UnitTests').getOrCreate()
```

Then it does have the sql property.

You can then use patch to refer to the spark object in the module where it gets initialised, we can be outside of the function under test, according to the following example:

Keeping module1 as per your original post with a change to how spark is created:

```
# module1.py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# CHANGED FROM GETACTIVESESSION
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('UnitTests').getOrCreate()


def filter_big_table(
    conditions = None,
) -> SparkDataFrame:

    sdf = spark.sql(f"select * from SUPER_BIG_TABLE")

    if conditions:
        sdf = sdf.filter(f.col("condition_col").isin(conditions))
    return sdf
```

Your test now reads:

```
# test.py
from unittest.mock import patch    
import module1


def test_filter_big_table():
    mock_data = ["list of data"]
    with patch("module1.spark.sql", return_value=mock_data):
        
        output_sdf = module1.filter_big_table() 
        # the call that reads...
        # sdf = spark.sql(f"select * from SUPER_BIG_TABLE") 
        # within this module should now return mock_data

    assert mock_data == output_sdf
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_filter_big_table()
```